# is there a function in python that could transform start end value tagging to bio tagging?

Tags: python, nlp

transform

```
{"ners": [[[1, 3, "label_one"], [3, 7, "label_x"], [9, 11, "label_y"]]], "sentences": [["现", "停", "经", "3", "8", "+", "周", "，", "无", "腹", "痛", "腹"]]}
```

to

```
"现"
"停" 
"经" 
"3" 
"8" 
"+" 
"周" 
"，" 
"无" 
"腹" 
"痛" 
"腹" 

o
B-label_one
I-label_one
B-label_x
I-label_x
I-label_x
I-label_x
o
b-label_y
I-label_y
I-label_y
o
```